# Microsoft BotFramework: Dual user inputs

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to create a bot, where users are able to select an option from an adaptive card, or type it in. So I am currently displaying a carousel of adaptive cards, and then using a text prompt for a possible input.

Unfortunately, since I'm using a prompt, when I click an action from the card, I get an "I don't understand" output from the bot, as it is expecting a user input.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mind sharing some piece of code?

Comment: In the .Messages controller you can check the value property of the activity, and assign that to the .Text property if present, THEN call the dialog handler.  This will ensure the .Prompt code functions as expected even when the card options are used.

Answer (score 5):

> I am currently displaying a carousel of adaptive cards, and then using a text prompt for a possible input.

I do a test and can reproduce the issue on my side. I assume that you call [PromptDialog.Text](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d9/d03/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_prompt_dialog.html#afa994f742676d605eef73404d22d1c6b) method after you send an adaptive card to client for collecting user inputs, the `PromptDialog.Text` would expect a string, if you directly enter the input filed(s) and submit it to bot, it will send back a Activity message with your input value, which would throw "I don't understand" message and let you retry again.

[image]

If you provide a string before you enter input field(s) and submit it, your bot should work as expected.

[image]